# 301 Redirection from no-www to www in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, apache2

I have a wordpress website in the folder: **/var/www/wordpress** and I have a domain called: *mydomain.com*.

In the hosting I did an **A REGISTER** with a zone **WWW**.

And now I need to do a 301 Redirection from http://midomain.com to http://www.midomain.com but what I'm trying doesn't work and the SEO checker doesn't validates my .htaccess

My .htaccess in **/var/www/wordpress/.htaccess** is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.midomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.midomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But doesn't work. Somewhere I red that you need to write the next lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.midomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.midomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Above # BEGIN Wordpress, but in my case doesn't work too.

Anyone knows how to do a 301 redirection from no-www to www in WordPress?

Thanks for your help and dedication.

PD: www.midomain.com doesn't exist, the real one is other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need .htacesss code. Please go to Admin panel settings and General tab... And than change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) with www version